# PHP undefined offset, involves file_put_contents and explode()

Tags: php

I am getting undefined offset. Please help, I can't find where's the problem at all :(

```
<?php

$fileTitle = $_GET['title'];
$rawData = $_GET['data'];

//fileTitle is testing
//rawData is 5000013,0.00,0.00,50.00,0+5006529,0.00,0.00,50.00,0

$lineData = explode("+",$rawData)

for( $i=0 ; $i<count($lineData) ; $i++)
{
    $txtFileTitle = $fileTitle.".txt";
    $txtFileLineData = $lineData[$i]."\r\n";

    $txtFileStatus = file_put_contents($txtFileTitle, $txtFileLineData, FILE_APPEND);

    if($txtFileStatus != false)
    {
        echo "SUCCESS: data written to txt file";
    }

    else
    {
        echo "FAIL: could not write to txt file";
    }
}?>
```

The result is a .txt file with:

5000013,0.00,0.00,50.00,0+5006529,0.00,0.00,50.00,0

What i want is a .txt with:

5000013,0.00,0.00,50.00,0

5006529,0.00,0.00,50.00,0

Comment: what is the error message? Almost certainly to do with `$lineData[$i]` in the loop. try `for( $i=0 ; $i<count($lineData) ; $i++)` rather than `for( $i=0 ; $i<=count($lineData) ; $i++)`

Comment: post the COMPLETE error message

Comment: Is there a problem related to an undefined index (maybe because your for loo runs till `$i <= count($lineData)` and not only till `$i < count($lineData)`) or something else?

Comment: I have edited the coding as someone pointed out the mistake. *Thanks*
But still, I can't get the output I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was due to the `<=` in the loop - as the counter begins at zero it would exceed the actual count by one and thus create the `undefined index` error.

```
<?php

    $title = $_GET['title'];
    $data = $_GET['data'];

    //title is testing
    //data is 5000013,0.00,0.00,50.00,0+5006529,0.00,0.00,50.00,0

    $lines = explode( "+", $data );
    $file = $title . ".txt";


    for( $i=0 ; $i < count( $lines ); $i++ ){
        $content = $lines[ $i ] . PHP_EOL;

        $status = file_put_contents( $file, $content, FILE_APPEND );

        echo $status ? 'SUCCESS: data written to txt file' : 'FAIL: could not write to txt file';
    }
?>
```

**edit**
The use of `+` in the source data is ambiguous because the `+` is used in urls when they are encoded ( space )

```
<?php

    $title = $_GET['title'];
    $data = urlencode( $_GET['data'] );

    $lines = explode( "+", $data );
    $file = __DIR__ . '/' . $title . ".txt";


    for( $i=0 ; $i < count( $lines ); $i++ ){
        $content = urldecode( $lines[ $i ] ) . PHP_EOL;

        $status = file_put_contents( $file, $content, FILE_APPEND );

        echo $status ? 'SUCCESS: data written to txt file' : 'FAIL: could not write to txt file';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and pointing out my mistake.
But unfortunately, again, I am getting 5000013,0.00,0.00,50.00,0 5006529,0.00,0.00,50.00,0. Not the way I want.

Comment: what is the expected output format? with a space between the lines?

Comment: Hmm, split by using "+" as reference. So I am expecting to get
$lineData[0] as 5000013,0.00,0.00,50.00,0
and
$lineData[1] as 5006529,0.00,0.00,50.00,0

Comment: The expected output is a txt file with contents as followed:




5000013,0.00,0.00,50.00,0
5006529,0.00,0.00,50.00,0

Comment: that's what it does - at least in testing here it writes 2 lines with that data

Comment: but why in the txt file, there's only 1 line? :(

Comment: ok - I see. I had statically declared the variables `$title` and `$data` rather than using the querystring. @rollstuhlfahrer actually mentioned this in his answer but deleted it

Comment: "The use of + in the source data is ambiguous "
@RamRaider Awesome. Now I know why. Thank you and everyone who help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simple to use `preg_replace` function to replace `+` whith space

```
$fileTitle = $_GET['title'];
$rawData = $_GET['data'];

$txtFileLineData = preg_replace('/\+/', ' ', $rawData);
$txtFileTitle = $fileTitle.".txt";
$txtFileStatus = file_put_contents($txtFileTitle, $txtFileLineData, FILE_APPEND);
if ($txtFileStatus != false) {
    echo "SUCCESS: data written to txt file";
} else {
    echo "FAIL: could not write to txt file";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion. May I request an example of using preg_replace for my coding here?

Comment: @iseedeadpeople I changed answer with yiour data

Comment: Thanks.
But the output is 5. Not the output I want :(

Comment: @iseedeadpeople then check `$_GET['data']` value